# how to redirect a % of traffic to different websites?

Tags: php, apache, logic

I am working on a LAMP(PHP) stack.

Scenario - I want to redirect the incoming traffic to the site to a different website based on a percentage.

Example : Main www.a.com. I have few other sites - www.a1.com, www.a2.com, www.b1.com, www.b2.com.

Now when the traffic comes to my main site www.a.com, I would like to divide the traffic like -

```
33% of traffic redirected to www.a1.com
33% of traffic redirected to www.a2.com
30% of traffic redirected to www.b1.com
4%  of traffic redirected to www.b2.com
```

how can i achieve this? I am a php developer so would like to do it through php, but also would like to know if any other technologies are involved.
------ updates ----

I want to achieve this functionality once the user clicks on the logout button on the main site.
Thanks,
Tanmay

Comment: Are you looking for a load balancing solution? If so, this is probably better suited on serverfault.com, and you should probably look on a deeper level than PHP

Comment: Are you doing this to spread the load? If so, you don't want to use PHP. (Something like a round robin DNS would be a better fit - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS)

Comment: No i am not doing to spread the load. basically i have an online app where on logout, i want the user to go to our different sites

Comment: @JMC, it may sound icky!:) but we have to go with the requirements :)

Answer (score 3):

Generate a random number between 1 and 100,

```
0-32 redirected to www.a1.com
33-65% redirected to www.a2.com
66-95% redirected to www.b1.com
96-99% redirected to www.b2.com
```

you can provide these functionalities using your server. Check out those keywords: nginx, round robin.

Comment: Alp Balkan, thanks for your reply, but I was trying to get more involved on php side. as commented above, I would like to redirect the user after they hit logout button

Comment: run above script after hitting logout button?

Comment: Hey @Ahmet, this wouldn't work I don't think.  Just because the the random number generator has a 4% chance of selecting a number between 96-100, _doesn't_ mean that 4% of _traffic_ will go to www.b2.com.  It would mean more that any random user would have a 4% chance of being redirected to www.b2.com.  I think the result however, would be different than sending 4% of traffic towards the site.

Comment: He requests for 'redirection'; not a masked load balancing option.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route_decider = rand(0, 99);

/**
/* Remember there should not be an output before the header response. Browsers must see HTTP header 
/* response first! Upon logout redirect to a page containing this code.
/*
 **/

if ( $router_decider >= 0 && $route_decider <= 32) # 33 %
    header( 'Location: http://www.a1.com' );

if ( $router_decider >= 33 && $route_decider <= 65) # 33 %
    header( 'Location: http://www.a2.com' );        

if ( $router_decider >= 66 && $route_decider <= 95) # 30 %
    header( 'Location: http://www.b1.com' );              

if ( $router_decider >= 96 && $route_decider <= 99) # 4 %
    header( 'Location: http://www.b2.com' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a few cents:

1. Put a proxy server as your initial target website. www.main-domain.com
2. Add a script here to divert your traffic
3. Diversion is based on %ge of traffic, so write code for counting your visitors to your main domain.
4. Make a session for your counter and start diverting. Count the per domain diversions and put in session.
5. Always check the session counter and make this redirection.

This is one base logic. You can expand or think similar lines.

If you have a firewall application, you might have the redirection settings based on %ge available there.

Thanks.